# angular ui-grid get name of column to be sorted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How do you get the name of the column that is supposed to be sorted? I need to pass this information to my function that gets data to achieve external sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `sortColumns` variable in the sort callback function gives you access to the columns.

You can get the name of the field like:

`sortColumns[0].field`